# what is the returnBooking() method supposed to do?

Tags: java, class, return

after I call this from other class I try to return to my previous class but It came out this error, below is my codes

```
public class Train extends Booking {
  public Train returnBooking(){
     int Tid,dest;
     Date now = new Date();
     Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
     Scanner sc2=new Scanner(System.in);
 try{     
     System.out.println("Enter train ID");
     System.out.println("(**Example '1001'**)");
     Tid=sc.nextInt();
     System.out.println("1. Malacca Zoo to Night Safari");
     System.out.println("2. Malacca Zoo to River Safari");
     System.out.println("3. River Safari to Malacca Zoo");
     System.out.println("Enter a destination for the train");
     dest = sc.nextInt();
     System.out.println("Enter date: ");
     String date = sc2.nextLine();

     SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");  
     Date testDate = null;  


     try{

        testDate = df.parse(date);    
    }catch(ParseException e){ System.out.println("invalid format");} 
    if (!df.format(testDate).equals(date)){  
        System.out.println("invalid date!!");  
    } else {  
        System.out.println("valid date");  
    } 
}catch(InputMismatchException e){System.out.print("Input must be numbers only");}
return Booking.class;**//imcompatible type**
 }
}
```

is my return method wrong? or just some simple mistake that I miss looked?

here is my Booking class's code

```
public class Booking{
public static void main(String[]agrs){
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

   int sel,book_ticket, reschedule, cancel, add, remove, display, total, loop;

   System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t****************************************************\t\t\t\t\t");
   System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t*              Welcome to Malacca Zoo              *\t\t\t\t\t");
   System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t*  This is our new online train reservstion system *\t\t\t\t\t");
   System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t*  follow the instruction at below to perform your *\t\t\t\t\t");
   System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t* reservation, hope you will enjoy our new services*\t\t\t\t\t");
   System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t****************************************************\t\t\t\t\t");
   System.out.println("\n\n1.Select and book a ticket ");
   System.out.println("2.Reschedule a train");
   System.out.println("3.Cancel a reservation");
   System.out.println("4.Add new train service");
   System.out.println("5.Remove a train from service");
   System.out.println("6.Display total number of passengers");
   System.out.println("7.Total profit from a service");
   System.out.println("0.Exit");
   System.out.println("\nEnter the number to select the function that you want to perform");

//try {
   sel=sc.nextInt();
   for(loop=0;loop<2;loop++)   {
      if (sel==0)
      {
          System.exit(0);  
      }
      else if(sel == 4)
      {
         new Train();
      }
      else
      {
           System.out.println("You enter an invalid number. Please try again");
           sel=sc.nextInt();
           loop=0;
       }
    }
 // } catch (InputMismatchException e){
 // } finally {
 // }
 // System.out.print("Input must be a number between 1 and 0: ");
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. The compiler is telling you it's wrong. The method should return an object ot type Train. You return an object of type java.lang.Class instead.

Comment: In that case how should I do to return to my previous class?

Comment: Maybe the question for MorganSim is `what is the returnBooking() method supposed to do?`

Comment: Maybe you are correct, I should change my question

Comment: @MorganSIm: if you don't know what your own program is supposed to do, how could we know?

Comment: @JB Nizet: I want it to return to previous class cause if not return I couldn't able to book the train but I don't know how to do the return class, so I try to learn from here

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. A method doesn't return to something. It returns something. A method `giveMeTheSalt()` returns the salt. Whoever calls this method gets back the salt. You should re-read your text book about what functions/methods are, and what a return value is, because you seem to be missing key algorithmic concepts.

Comment: Ok, I'll learn it again thanks for helping me to find out where is my problem

Answer (score 0):

You defined your method to return a `Train` type while you are returning a `class`.

try to change your code to something like this:

```
public Train returnBooking(){
    //code
    Train trainObject = new Train();
    // code to fill the Train object.
    return new trainObject();
}
```

Or simply return nothing since you don't do any processing on any `Train` object.

```
return null;
```

Or i recommend to declare your method as `void`, because it seem like you don't do any thing with a `Train` object. you didn't even declared any object from `Train` or `Booking` classes.

```
public void returnBooking(){
    //code
}
```

Comment: Returning a Booking from a method supposed to return a Train won't help much.

Comment: the return null; is function but when I run the code it display nothing like it just skipping this part

Comment: Returning a Booking from a void method won't compile either.

Comment: it become cannot return a value form method whose result type is void

Comment: @JBNizet if you read my comment above making the method void, you should know that i forget to remove the return statement.

Comment: @Salah: the OP is lost and doesn't understand what return means. Posting incorrect return statements will make him even more lost. That's why I downvoted, and explained you why. I have now removed my downvote. Bu please be more careful with your answers.

Comment: Yea But you know that i left it by mistake, you could correct me or hint for that, anyway, i just updated my answer.

Comment: @Salah: Thanks for trying to help me, I've learn that what I'm trying to do is impossible to be done thanks for your help anywhere, I hope some day I'll meet another pblm that ur solution will help me

Comment: @Salah: That's what I did: *Returning a Booking from a void method won't compile either.* I also hinted you before, for your previous mistake: *Returning a Booking from a method supposed to return a Train won't help much.*.

Answer (score 0):

Before asking questions make sure you have right knowledge in java!!.

How could you return java.lang.Class type  instead of java.lang.Object of type Train???

Definetly compiler will cry with your code.